# Were pigs made haram because they were going to be extinct?

Tags: history, source-identification, pork

Unfortunately I cannot provide citation for this as I read it online years ago. But an Islamic scholar mentioned that **his** belief (I admired this scholar as he encouraged Muslims to learn and interpret Islam for themselves and not blindly follow others, even himself!) was that pigs were being consumed at an alarming rate during the first few centuries AD.

Therefore, in order to save them, Allah made them haram (forbidden).

**Are there any sources to back this claim?**

Comment: This shows no research effort, and is merely idiosyncratic opinion.

Comment: @MoziburUllah - Should I have mentioned Yahoo or Google? I disagree that I did not perform adequate research, I **always** do before posting questions. Also, I used the [source-identification](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) tag since I cannot find the source.

Comment: Which only goes to show that it is mere idiosyncratic opinion - which the answer below supports; Mary Douglas, the anthropologist traces it to notions of warding of pollution, for example.

Comment: Not everything a scholar says should be taken at face-value; sometimes they can joke. Real research doesn't mean just using google or yahoo to dig up, on the whole, random ideas; but ideas that are reasonably grounded in the literature - and given your subject I'd judge that to be anthropology or the sociology of religion. And that's what I'm pointing out - there's nothing on your question to show that you've looked there.

Comment: :D facepalm for that scholar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people have tried to give reason to Allah subhana wa-ta'ala's decree that pigs are haram.

Your scholars claim, though I respect it, doesn't seem to have any basis. The domestication of pigs had been [studied](http://blogs.nature.com/freeassociation/2015/01/on-the-history-of-pigs.html). And this study does not appear to mention any population decline at any point actual or that pigs were ever threatened.

Pigs are omnivores and scavengers *by nature*.  That is even if they are bred solely on vegetable, they will, given the opportunity, return to scavenging. These are categories of haram meat (so one would imagine other scavengers/omnivores like rats are equally impermissible) and perhaps pigs are singled out due to the fact they had been widely domesticated.

Ultimately only Allah knows why, however. While it can beneficial to speculate *in an attempt to better understand our deen*, it is also wise not to go too far with such conjecture.

Answer (score 4):

First of all it ought to be paid attention that there can be found many items that Allah made it haram, but there are not complete explanation about all the reasons.

Secondly it doesn’t to be considered as the reason as what you pointed out “Were pigs made haram because they were going to be extinct?”

Thirdly there would definitely be one or even many reasons for the things which have been haram by Allah, and in other word it is related to the Hekmah (theology). But occasionally it is not directly mentioned their reasons in many items.

Fourthly it can be inferred from different sources that the most possibly reason of the Hormah of pork (pig) is related to its negative effect on the health of the body as there seems to be many different viruses and so forth into its pork.

---

**References and more info.**

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa768)

[www.al-islam.org (English)](http://www.al-islam.org/philosophy-islamic-laws-nasir-makarim-shirazi-jafar-subhani/question-16-harmful-effects-pork-health)

[Why pork (pig) is haram? (Farsi)](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa19764)

Answer (score 2):

Assalaamu alaikum warehmatullahi wabarkatuhu

There are many, innumerable reasons when Allah creates a creature or being every individual has his own purpose to serve. You can simply derive from their habits or behavior is a first step by observing. *Note: this is my personal view.*

Pigs eat garbage correct? One of their purpose could be to eliminate trash in the earth? But Allah knows best. And thus eating it may cause various deadly diseases.

What Allah creates is his wish and If Allah commands to keep away from it then you should obey as he also tests his faithful slaves!

Answer (score -3):

The scholar you had admired has said wrong.
And the actual reason is pigs were made haram because pigs are the dirtiest animals on this planet.
Apart from this Islam is a pure and cleanest religion and Allah loves people who are clean.so we do ablution and wudu before Salah or salath or namaz or Islamic prayer. Apart from this just visit youtube for the harmful effects caused by eating pig.

Comment: And yet you are able to contract far worse diseases from sheep (foot and mouth disease) and from cows (BSE) and from chicken (Salmonella,  campylobacter). So your line of reasoning is flawed.